# Office 365 REST Calendar API for creating events failing with HTTP - 403 when authenticated using OAuth bearer token

Tags: api, rest, azure, oauth, office365

My azure hosted web API uses the O365 Calendar and Mail REST APIs for creating events and mails on behalf of the users. All necessary permissions have been enabled for the corresponding Azure AD application. My question - Accessing the mail API using the Bearer OAuth token as part of the header succeeds but when I use the same token for the events API, it fails with a 403. 
The Documentation I have been following for my implementation is the official msdn one and the update - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/6fc135ae-f8f9-4b4d-b50b-f00a2bd79a30/office-365-rest-api-mail-calendar-contacts-update?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

```
Fiddler trace (Raw view of request) - 
POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/OData/Me/Events HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
client-request-id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Authorization: Bearer <OAuth token>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: outlook.office365.com
Content-Length: 287
Expect: 100-continue

{"Attendees":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"sample@sample.com","Name":null},"Type":"Required"}],"Body":{"Content":"Hello World","ContentType":"HTML"},"End":"2014-10-22T19:00:00Z","Location":{"DisplayName":"Conf Room M"},"Start":"2014-10-22T18:00:00Z","Subject":"Testing"}

Text view of response -
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}

Fiddler trace of the Mail API request that works fine -
POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/OData/Me/sendmail HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
client-request-id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Authorization: Bearer <OAuth Token>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: outlook.office365.com
Content-Length: 171
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"Message":{"Body":{"Content":"Test","ContentType":"HTML"},"Subject":"test","ToRecipients":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"sample@sample.com","Name":null}}]}}
```

Comment: What resource ID are you using to get the bearer token?

Comment: Resource ID - https://outlook.office365.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for having kept this question hanging.
The issue was with the ClientSecret (either had stale permissions on it or was wrong in the first place). Generating a new one via the management portal fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are getting a 403 (Forbidden) error for one API, I'd suggest you review the resources enabled for the application. Can you make sure you have Write permissions for the Calendar API? I know you mentioned that you've done this before, I'm just checking in case of the small chance you missed those Write perms.